# Filter variable names from a codebook, and apply a pivot function

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have two dataframes, where one contains data and the other contains a description of said data. The first has an ID column, and then one column for each variable-year (I'll put an example at the bottom). I want a result with a new dataframe having the description as a variable name, and one column pr. variable and a new year-variable. To achieve this I have so for created this function:

```
Add_year_var <- function(Data, navn){
Years <-  unique(Data$Aar)
Data <- Data %>%
  distinct(Aar, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(Aar, values_to = "year")
NewData <- KomSPSS %>%
select(ID, Data$variable)
colnames(NewData) <- c("Kommune", Years)
NewData <- NewData %>%
 pivot_longer(2:ncol(NewData), names_to = "year", values_to = navn)
}
```

Based on finding the variable in the codebook using `filter(str_detect(Desc, "name_here")`, creating a new dataframe on which I can apply the function. This new data has then been joined into a third dataframe containing all variables.

However, the data contains nearly 2000 variables, so doing this by hand would take a considerable amount of time. I wondered therefore whether there was a way to do this on all rows at once, either using an apply-function or a for-loop. Using these, however, I haven't been able to figure out how to filter out which variables belong together, nor how to name these. I tried making a new function containing:

```
FltDes <- function(name){
       filter(str_detect(Desc, name)
      }
```

Making this a part of the function above, the plan being that I then could give each row in the codebook to the "name"-argument, however it did not allow for the name-argument to be used as a pattern for the str_detect-function. Any clues on how this can be done? All help is appreciated!

Edit: New Dataframes

The data consists of two dataframes, one which contains the data, and another showing the name and year for each column in the data.

Codebook:

|  | ID | Aar | Desc | pos | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1898 | Effektivt stemmeberettigede: I alt | 1338 | V1338 |
| 6 | 2 | 1901 | Stemmeberettigede: Kvinner | 1343 | V1343 |
| 7 | 3 | 1901 | Effektivt stemmeberettigede: Menn | 1345 | V1345 |
| 5 | 4 | 1901 | Stemmeberettigede: Menn | 1342 | V1342 |
| 4 | 5 | 1901 | Antall valgsogn | 1341 | V1341 |
| 21 | 6 | 1901 | Effektivt stemmeberettigede: I alt | 1347 | V1347 |
| 3 | 7 | 1907 | Effektivt stemmeberettigede: I alt | 1373 | V1373 |
| 41 | 8 | 1910 | Effektivt stemmeberettigede: I alt | 1381 | V1381 |

Data/KomSPSS:

|  | V1338 | V1343 | V1345 | V1342 | V1341 | V1347 | V1373 | V1381 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 972 | 1225 | 1648 | 1732 | 1 | 2871 | 3128 | 3995 | 1 |
| 2 | 409 | 702 | 799 | 838 | 1 | 1492 | 2196 | 2953 | 2 |
| 3 | 1138 | 1628 | 2037 | 2143 | 1 | 3660 | 4462 | 5227 | 3 |
| 4 | 694 | 1058 | 1278 | 1345 | 1 | 2314 | 2537 | 3095 | 4 |
| 5 | 511 | 451 | 650 | 660 | 1 | 1101 | 1258 | 1461 | 5 |
| 6 | 468 | 610 | 935 | 963 | 2 | 1545 | 1752 | 2234 | 6 |
| 7 | 143 | 128 | 225 | 235 | 1 | 353 | 408 | 508 | 7 |
| 8 | 496 | 444 | 890 | 925 | 3 | 1334 | 1621 | 2011 | 8 |

From the codebook I then make a new dataframe, containing a unique description:

```
NewData <- Codebook %>%
         filter(str_detect("Effektivt stemmeberettigede: I alt")
```

To this new dataframe I can then apply the function:

```
Result <- add_year_variable(NewData, 
          "Effektivt_stemmeberettigede_I_alt")
```

Resulting in this final dataframe:

|  | Kommune | year | Effektivt_stemmeberettigede_I_alt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1898 | 972 |
| 2 | 1 | 1901 | 1225 |
| 3 | 1 | 1907 | 3128 |
| 4 | 1 | 1910 | 3995 |
| 5 | 2 | 1898 | 409 |
| 6 | 2 | 1901 | 702 |
| 7 | 2 | 1907 | 2196 |
| 8 | 2 | 1910 | 2953 |
| 9 | 3 | 1898 | 1138 |
| 10 | 3 | 1901 | 1628 |
| 11 | 3 | 1907 | 4462 |
| 12 | 3 | 1910 | 5227 |
| 13 | 4 | 1898 | 694 |
| 14 | 4 | 1901 | 1058 |
| 15 | 4 | 1907 | 2537 |
| 16 | 4 | 1910 | 3095 |
| 17 | 5 | 1898 | 511 |
| 18 | 5 | 1901 | 451 |
| 19 | 5 | 1907 | 1258 |
| 20 | 5 | 1910 | 1461 |
| 21 | 6 | 1898 | 468 |
| 22 | 6 | 1901 | 610 |
| 23 | 6 | 1907 | 1752 |
| 24 | 6 | 1910 | 2234 |
| 25 | 7 | 1898 | 143 |
| 26 | 7 | 1901 | 128 |
| 27 | 7 | 1907 | 408 |
| 28 | 7 | 1910 | 508 |
| 29 | 8 | 1898 | 496 |
| 30 | 8 | 1901 | 444 |
| 31 | 8 | 1907 | 1621 |
| 32 | 8 | 1910 | 2011 |

Comment: okay, I see the Data-df and the Codebook. How dows your expected output look like?

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I added an edit showing what I hope to be the result

Comment: Your first data.frame states for ID `1` and `V1` a value of `23`. Your second one ("Codebook") has for ID `1` a pos of `V1`. How do you create the column `SailorsAtSea` for ID `1` and year `1991` with a value of `3`?

Comment: That was just a typo, you're absolutely right that would not make sense

Comment: I really want to help you solving your problem, but actually I don't understand your logic, how to compose the desired output from the original two datasets. Now you stated, that there was a typo. How does the corrected version looks like?

Comment: I've added an example that is directly from my own script, so this should work. I truly do appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: Why has "Kommune 6" in "year 1901" a value of 601 instead of 1545, which is the value of V1347 and ID 6 in your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data looks like shown above.

First we filter for "Effektivt_stemmeberettigede:_I_alt":

```
library(tidyverse)

codebook <- codebook %>% 
  filter(Desc == "Effektivt_stemmeberettigede:_I_alt")
```

Next we combine `codebook` and `data`:

```r
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to="variable") %>% 
  left_join(codebook, by=c("ID", "variable")) %>% 
  select(Kommune = ID, year = Aar, Desc, value) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="Desc")
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Kommune  year `Effektivt_stemmeberettigede:_I_alt`
    <dbl> <dbl>                                <dbl>
1       1  1898                                  972
2       6  1901                                 1545
3       7  1907                                  408
4       8  1910                                 2011
```